# Redirect request from angularjs to another server with asp.net webapi 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have 2 server: 1 with a Front end (AngularJs + Asp.net); the second one is a back end that expose some services with Web API 2.0.

When I do a request using angularjs, the request arrive on the first server instead of the back end server.

```
angular.module("public-area")
    .factory("MyService", function ($resource) {
        return {
            myService: $resource("api/MyService/")
        };
    });
```

But on the front end server there is no web api that answer the request (obviously).
I could easily "redirect" the request on my back end server if I changed the code in this way;

```
            myService: $resource("http://myBackEndServer/api/MyService/")
```

But it is not what I want. I want all my request pass from front end server and then to back end server. There is a way to configure the server in order to redirect all requests to back end for example in the application start when I do:

```
//Web Api configuration
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
});
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Is there a specific requirement that impedes you from making direct calls to your API endpoint? You seems to need to implement some kind of proxy in you front-end.

Comment: No, the only reason is that I would like to centralize on server (for example, in the web.config of the front end) which is the back end server to call... I do not want to write the back end server address in a js file... my problem is just for maintainability... too many points to edit when I pass from dev env to prod env... I would like to have everything in the web.config

Comment: Just one more thing: what are you using in your front-end project? It is an MVC app and your Views are .cshtml files? Or it is just an empty project?

Comment: No, sadly not... It's Asp.net... simply asp.net...